# socket.io is not initialised on the first request

Tags: socket.io, gunicorn, flask-socketio

I'm using socket.io with flask-socketio running on gunicorn and nginx.
I'm able to emit messages successfully and everything works normally.
The only problem is after I restart gunicorn , the socket is not initialised the first time I load  the page(first request to the server after restart). Everything works as intended from the second request onwards.

This is how i initialise the socket

```
var socket= io();
socket.on('connected', function(msg) {
    user_id = msg['user_id'];
    console.log('Connected', user_id);
});
```

and on the server side

```
socketio = SocketIO(app,message_queue="amqp://test:test@localhost", cors_allowed_origins="*")

@socketio.on('connect')
def test_connect():
    print("socket.io")
    user_id = request.sid
    emit('connected',  {'user_id': user_id}, room=user_id)
```

gunicorn is run as

```
gunicorn -k gevent -w 1 wsgi:app --bind unix:app.sock -m 007 --timeout 100
```

Comment: By "it is not initialized", do you mean that your `connected` handler does not run? Have you enabled logging on server and client to see if there are any clues there?

Comment: The connected handler does not run and I did not see any clues in the logs. But I can see the initial request by socket.io in the access logs. From the next request onward (eg. if i reload the page) the same code works fine.

Comment: Create a small and complete example and I'll debug it here. Other than that I do not know how I can help you figure this out.

Comment: I think i figured how the problem is caused. I run a celery task in the background use ```emit``` to send messages from  inside the process. Using ```SocketIO(message_queue="amqp://test:test@localhost") ``` does not work as the messages are not being sent(using ```emit```)  but using
```SocketIO(app, message_queue="amqp://test:test@localhost" )``` does work. The problem I described only happens when using ```SocketIO(message_queue="amqp://test:test@localhost") ```.

Comment: [this](https://github.com/SteveEmmanuel/socketio_test) is the link to the repository with the example code.

Comment: For your server you have to initialize `SocketIO(app, message_queue='...')`. For Celery you have to do `SocketIO(message_queue='...')`. Does that work if you do it that way?

Comment: I did try that but came up with the same results. Don’t know what I’m doing wrong.

Comment: I have no way to verify or confirm that you have implemented my suggestion correctly. Can you update your question with what you've done?